# Parse JSON Nested SubValues in Powershell to Table

Tags: json, csv, powershell, parent-child

I converted the JSON string to Powershell in v5.  The original json string is below:

```
$j = @'
[{
    "id": "1",
    "Members": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "Members": [
        "A",
        "C"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "Members": [
        "A",
        "D"
    ]
}]
'@

$json = $j | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I would like the result set to look like the result set below.  Eventually I will export to SQL:

```
 id     Members
-----   --------
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       C
3       A
3       D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$json | % {
    $id = $_.id
    $_.members | select @{n='id';e={$id}}, @{n='members';e={$_}}
}
```